# Parse XML in Jenkins Pipeline - No such property: testsuite for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: xml, jenkins, xml-parsing, jenkins-pipeline

I am using `XMLParse` to parse XML in Jenkins Pipeline.

```
<testsuites name="Mocha Tests">
  <testsuite name="Customer Personal Informations Retrieving personal information data Valid params" tests="1" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" timestamp="2019-08-30T20:37:26" time="0.422">
    <testcase classname="Customer Personal Informations Retrieving personal information data Valid params" name="When try to get all personal information data, then it should the fields" time="0.157">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Customer Personal Informations Retrieving personal information data Invalid params" tests="2" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" timestamp="2019-08-30T20:37:26" time="0.261">
    <testcase classname="Customer Personal Informations Retrieving personal information data Invalid params" name="When get personal informations without valid token, then it shouldnt return fields" time="0.009">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I want to know if there are any errors in any of the `testsuite` field.

For that, I am using and getting `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testsuite for class: groovy.lang.Binding` error.

```
def test_report = readFile "report.xml"
def xml = new XmlParser()
def test_report_xml = xml.parseText(test_report)

test_report_xml.each{
    echo testsuite.@errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using groovy .each()

so since you haven't declared a name for each item it will be `it`

```
 test_report_xml.each{
    echo it.@errors
 }
```

Alternatively, name the var:

```
 test_report_xml.each{ testsuite ->
    echo testsuite.@errors
 }
```